# Flip a biased coin and get an arbitrary amount of heads in a row for an arbitrary probability

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

- I toss a coin with probability of tails being 0.8 and heads being 0.2
- Given $\epsilon > 0$, we want the probability of getting $k$ heads to be $<\epsilon$. Show a formula to choose the length $m$ of the message.

---

I've started working out this problem, but unfortunately I can't figure out how to scale my solution up to work for any arbitrary length. Here's what I've done so far:

If I wanted the probability of getting 10 heads in a row, that would simply be $\Pr (10\text{ heads})=0.2^{10}$. If I wanted to get $k$ heads in a row that would be $0.2^k$.

If I wanted to scale this to choose the length of the message $m$ such that the probability of getting $k$ heads is $<\epsilon$, what should I try doing?

Comment: The probability of getting at least $k$ heads in a message of length $m$ is 
$$
\sum_{i=k}^m \binom mi \left(\frac15\right)^i\left(\frac45\right)^{m-i}.
$$

Comment: Am I missing something obvious...?  The more you flip, the great the chance you will get $k$ heads (even though $P(H) = 0.2 < 0.5$ for each flip), whether in a row, or in total.  The best way to make getting $k$ heads unlikely, is to flip no coins, or $n$ coins where $n < k$.  Then the prob $=0 < \epsilon$.  Are you perhaps being asked to find the _maximum_ $m$ while maintaining $P(k\ heads) < \epsilon$?